# How to create and extract an image from a scanned PDF file (Java)

Tags: java

I´m using JAVA and I´m trying to extract or save images files from a scanned pdf. The problem is that i only get black images. I just want to crop a logo (can be blackandwhite) from scanned pdf´s.

anyone has idea? or examples?

Advance thanks for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.
I used ImageMagick and Ghostscript libs. Then I used this on my JAVA project:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c convert -density 400x400 -layers flatten pdffile.pdf[0] tmp.png");
```